# SIGSEGV Error (Probably Array Index Out Of Bound)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Can anybody please help to find an error in this code? I am not able to get the error, & its giving a Runtime error. I checked all loops used for matrix but not able to find an error.

```
    int  n, arr[n][n];
    cin>>n;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            prev = ne;
            ne = 0;

            if(arr[i][j] == 1)
            {
                ne = i+j;
                prev = i+j;
                sum = ne - prev; 
                if(sum<0)
                    sum=-sum;
                steps+=sum;
            }           
            c++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you declare `arr`?

Comment: @Zeta Check the code, I've added it now.

Comment: You mean 'int  n, arr[n][n];' ??

Comment: You are aware that array indices start at zero?

Comment: I've tried with 0 indices also, its giving the same error @MartinJames

Comment: Initialize `n` to the value of your choice, initialize `i` and `j` to `0`, use `< n` instead of `<= n` in your loop conditions.

Comment: Please do not edit code in questions so as to invalidate answers that already exist; it's very annoying to those contributors that spent time on answering:(

Comment: Sorry @MartinJames, my intentions were not to invalidate answers, but to provide complete code so contributors can review complete code which will help them to give proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using variable n to create array without initializing it.[You must always use a constant for initializing a static array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

do something like this:

```
const int  n = SOME_VALUE;
int arr[n][n];
//rest remains same
```

also, you should use < n instead of <= n as pointed out by John.

if you want a dynamic array , then using [STL vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) will be better.

Comment: Even if it was initialized, he will get an error: `i<=n` should be `i<n`,

Comment: I've initialized it, The value is taken from user in other part of code.

Comment: @KiranMalvi that may be, but 'int  n, arr[n][n];' suggests otherwise.

Comment: @MartinJames Ohh yeah got my error. Before even initializing value to var n i was putting n to arr[n][n]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising the `n` variable and also your loop should be

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Array indices in C++ start from zero

Same for the j loop

Comment: Obi-Wan errors? hmm, I know of yoda expressions
http://www.devsanon.com/2015/11/usefulness-of-yoda-expressions-in.html
but Obi-Wan errors? never heard of those